# Django - Date field support time zone?

Tags: django

I'm working with Django `Date` field and was wondering if it supports time zone. Doesn't seem like it does because when I attach a time zone to the date it gives an error. Is there a reason for this? Wouldn't something like 11:30pm PST at 12/20/2021 give like 12/21/2021 in UTC?

Answer (score 0):

Django [supports](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/) timezones.

In common case all you need to do is set the proper variables in `settings.py`:

```
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
```